# google-app-engine: How can I have a list of objects as property in another class?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

how can I achieve this in `google appengine db model`

```
from google.appengine.ext import db
Class Car(db.Model):
    name=db.StringProperty()
    model=db.StringProperty()
    mileage=db.IntegerProperty()

Class Person(db.Model):
    name=db.StringProperty()
    age=db.IntegerProperty()
    cars=db.ListProperty(Car) # How can I have cars object for person containing list of Car Objects?
```

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at the reference documentation http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/datamodeling.html#References

It works the other way round, class Car would have

```
person = db.ReferenceProperty(Person, collection_name="cars")
```

which would make a property cars available in Person.

Hope this helps.