# google-app-engine: How to apply filter in query when filter parameter is db.ReferenceProperty?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, gql

This is next step to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8485502/google-app-engine-how-can-i-have-a-list-of-objects-as-property-in-another-class) question, where I need to run queries and apply filters. 
Here is my Model

```
from google.appengine.ext import db
Class Car(db.Model):
    name=db.StringProperty()
    model=db.StringProperty()
    mileage=db.IntegerProperty()
    person = db.ReferenceProperty(Person, collection_name='person')

Class Person(db.Model):
    name=db.StringProperty()
    age=db.IntegerProperty()
```

**Question** : For a Person I want to get all the cars he own

**Approach** : Get all the cars and apply filter on person whose name is "Random"
I tried the following but it doesn't work

```
s = Car.all()
s.filter('person.name =', 'Random') # It fails here
result = s.fetch(1)[0] # just first result for now
print result.text
print result.votes
print result.page.language
```

How can I make this query run?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only use filter on indexed attributes. `person.name` is from other entity! In sql you would need to use [join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29) (which is impossible when data grows big), in google bigtable like in many other non-relational databases tables `join` is not possible. Luckily your case is very simple, you can select all cars if you know persons key:

```
>>> person = Person.all().filter('name =', 'Mr. Random').fetch(1)[0]
>>> cars = Car.all().filter('person =', person.key())
```

If you had used a more reasonable value for `collection_name`

```
Class Car(db.Model):
    ...    
    person = db.ReferenceProperty(Person, collection_name='cars_collection')
```

you could access all cars like this:

```
>>> person = Person.all().filter('name =', 'Mr. Random').fetch(1)[0]
>>> mrs_randoms_cars = person.cars_collection
```

Comment: This works very well, thank you, but it will make two DB calls one for person fetch and another for mrs_randoms_cars.fetch(), right? is there a way to make just one db call?

Comment: The only other way is to add `person_name` attribute to car.

Comment: `fetch(1)[0]` is just a complex and error prone way of doing `get()`.

Comment: `get()` only works if you know the Key. In this example it does not work.